# MySQL use comma separated values to link two tables

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a logical problem with combining two table, but one table have comma separated value.

**Table1**

```
user    value
-----------------
Alex    x1,x2
Max     x2,x3
```

**Table2**

```
    valueId valueProperties
    -----------------
    x1         abc
    x2         asd
    x3         poi
```

I whant to make a query and select `user` with `valueProperties` from second table instead `value` from first table.

```
select user, valueProperties from Table1, ....
```

I looking for a result search something like:

```
Alex abc,asd
```

Comment: Comma separated values that refer to another table is incorrect by design. You need a (new) table where you have rows 1) Alex; x1 2) Alex; x2 3) Max; x2 4) Max; x3

Comment: Do you have a possibility to refactor your table?

Comment: It is not my table, is what I receive. I have 11k row to procese.

Comment: One option is to create a script that iterates over all records of old table and copies the values over to new table that has correct design. If the old table keeps chaning then add a trigger that makes respective changes to the new table whenever there are changes in the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally this is a bad design. You should properly normalize your tables in your tables. Anyway, to answer your question directly, you can use MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET` to search for a value in a csv. The `GROUP_CONCAT` will concatenate row into csv format.

```
SELECT  a.user,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.valueProperties)
FROM    Table1 a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.valueID, a.value) > 0
GROUP   BY a.user
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e76951/2)

Suggested schema design:

UserList

- UserID
- UserName
- other columns...

ValueList

- ValueID
- ValueProperty
- other columns...

UserValue

- UserID
- ValueID

Comment: add brief for group_concat character length limitation also so OP would be aware of this issue

Comment: It's working... THANK YOU. This is not my database, I will create a new table for this project.